# Set a default attribute for the first user of a company when they register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried this:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  after_action :set_default_role, only: [:create]

  private
    def set_default_role
      @users.role ||= 'admin'
    end
end
```

But it's not assigning the role to use user (in a nested attributes form).

Update:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_default_role

  belongs_to :company

  def set_default_role
    if Company.user.first
      @user.role ||= 'admin'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This should be done in the model layer.

Comment: See my update. I know user is undefined, but not sure how I should limit the `after_action` to only applying to the first user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the chat discussion with OP, OP had a nested form, while creating a Company a single user was getting created. There was only one change required in `CompaniesController#create` action:

```
  def create
    params[:company][:users_attributes]["0"][:role] = "admin"  ## Add this
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    if @company.save
      redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.'
    else
     render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_default_role

  belongs_to :company

  def set_default_role
    if User.where(:company_id => company.id).empty?
      self.role ||= 'admin'
    end
  end
end
```